# Is it possible to change the XBMC video output to X11 (XCB) on Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, xbmc

I was just wondering if it's possible to change the XBMC output to X11 video output (XCB), just like in VLC?

I've searched all over the place, but can't seem to find any information about that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apparently it's not possible to change the XBMC output to X11 video output(XCB), this only seems to be available in VLC.

Nevertheless I managed to find a workaround to eliminate the video tearing in XBMC. This workaround has been only tested in Xubuntu 14.04 with Compton as it's default compositor. Unfortunately the default xfce compositor does not work properly with my Nvidia GeForce GT 755 even when v-blank is enabled in the default xfce compositor and in the Nvidia settings.

To completely fix your XBMC screen tearing with the specific graphics card above:

1. Go to `/home/<yourusername>/.config` and open the `compton.conf` file with a text editor of your choice.
2. Navigate to the line :

   ```
   unredir-if-possible = true;
   ```

   and change it to:

   ```
   unredir-if-possible = false;
   ```

Voilà, I have been tear free in XBMC ever since!